# Filter list of string dates for specific day of week

Tags: python

Given a list containing dates as part of a string:

```
['2021/08/01/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/02/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/03/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/04/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/05/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/06/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/08/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/09/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/10/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/11/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/12/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/13/EUR_USD.json',
 '2021/08/15/EUR_USD.json']
```

I want to filter and return only the date and only for Sundays.

This can be done with a list comprehension as follows but I would be interested in other ways of doing this:

```
def dayOfWeek(l):
    subset = ['/'.join(i.split("/")[0:3])
         for i in l 
             if datetime.strptime('/'.join(
                 i.split("/")[0:3]),'%Y/%m/%d' ).weekday()  == 6 ]
    return subset

['2021-08-01', '2021-08-08', '2021-08-15']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List-comprehension is fine, but another way is to use `filter` builtin

```py
list(filter(lambda x:datetime.strptime(x.rsplit('/', 1)[0], '%Y/%m/%d').weekday()==6, l))

['2021/08/01/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/08/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/15/EUR_USD.json']
```

There are other things you can do:

1. Instead of splitting and joining the strings, you can use `rsplit`, with `maxsplit=1`, then take the first item after the split
2. You are unnecessarily converting `/` delimited date string to `-` delimited date string by 
   `'-'.join(i.split("/")[0:3]),'%Y-%m-%d' )` which is useless

Comment: I like the `rsplit` approach thanks.  Regarding 2 I'm not sure what you mean by useless as it works.  I've updated and changed "-" to "/" as it looks better but please explain why useless as I'm possibly missing something.  I do prefer your approach though.  Many thanks

Comment: In this `'-'.join(i.split("/")[0:3]),'%Y-%m-%d' )` expression, you are splitting the string on `/`, and joining first three items by `-`, the character to split and join are different, that's what I was pointing out @nipy

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `calendar` module with an assignment expression for a shorter comprehension:

```
import calendar as cl, re
l = ['2021/08/01/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/02/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/03/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/04/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/05/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/06/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/08/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/09/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/10/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/11/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/12/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/13/EUR_USD.json', '2021/08/15/EUR_USD.json']
r = ['-'.join(d) for i in l if cl.weekday(*map(int, (d:=re.findall('\d+', i)))) == 6]
```

Output:

```
['2021-08-01', '2021-08-08', '2021-08-15']
```

Comment: I like the regex approach.  Thanks